# What is the best piece of recursion code you have come across?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming

Cases where really complex logic was simplified because of recursion, cases where recursion is used in everyday programming

Answer (score 2):

An astonishing case of recursion is the fixed point combinator in Haskell and related languages:

```
fix f = f (fix f)
```

which allows us to write recursive functions *without* explicit recursion:

```
fac = go (fix go) where
    go g 0 = 1
    go g n = n * g (n-1)
```

though it is not really that useful, because Haskell has recursion baked in, of course.

What is more is that the same trick works also on the type level. Here is a type that models a file system like directory structure:

```
data DirEntry a = Dir [(String, a)] | File String
data Fix t = Y (t (Fix t))
type Directory = Fix DirEntry
```

In this way, we can, in effect, work with values of type

```
DirEntry (DirEntry (DirEntry (DirEntry ...)))  -- nested arbitrarily deep
```

without `Directory` or `DirEntry` itself being recursive.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite use of recursion is trampolining.  It's a handy way to build composable code that does not overflow the call stack in languages without tail call elimination.

Here's a great example taken from [Rich Dougherty’s blog](http://blog.richdougherty.com/2009/04/tail-calls-tailrec-and-trampolines.html):

```
sealed trait Bounce[A]
case class Done[A](result: A) extends Bounce[A]
case class Call[A](thunk: () => Bounce[A]) extends Bounce[A]

def even2(n: Int): Bounce[Boolean] = {
  if (n == 0) Done(true)
  else Call(() => odd2(n - 1))
}

def odd2(n: Int): Bounce[Boolean] = {
  if (n == 0) Done(false)
  else Call(() => even2(n - 1))
}

def trampoline[A](bounce: Bounce[A]): A = bounce match {
  case Call(thunk) => trampoline(thunk())
  case Done(x) => x
}

trampoline(even2(9999)) // false
```

I also highly recommend Rúnar Óli's [paper on free monads](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2012/05/15/stackless-scala-with-free-monads-2/).

Comment: Of course, in a language without TCE you'd write `trampoline` iteratively...